# MVC - how to retrieve multiple records in a controller

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have the following action:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext(); 
    MyRecord r = rc.MyRecords.Single(x => x.RecordID == _id);

    return View(r);
 }
```

But turns out there are multiple records with the same id (table's primary key is a composite key). So I need to retrieve a List of type MyRecord, so I changed the code to:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext(); 
    List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Any(x => x.RecordID == id);

    return View(rl);
 }
```

But the above is clearly incorrect since method Any returns bool. Can someone help me correct my code?

Comment: Do `rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id);` instead

Comment: I don't see the link with sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Details(String id)
{
    MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext();
    List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id).ToList();

    return View(rl);
}
```

That will return all matches with `RecordID == id`, then pass this list off to your view. Just make sure you update the `Details` view as well to accept `List<MyRecord>` instead of `MyRecord` (now that you're passing a collection).

Comment: Thank you! Compiled without an issue

Answer (score 1):

In Linq, [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) just returns a true/false is any of the values match. You are looking for a simple [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id);
```